# Trigonometric identity related to unit circle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I really need help for this

Given that $\displaystyle\sin A = \frac35$, $\displaystyle\tan B = -\frac{5}{12}$ and that $A$ and $B$ lie in the same quadrant, find $\sin B$.

Comment: Only given the tangent, you can recover the sine up to a sign, which is given by the value of $\sin A$. Do you know anything about how $\tan$ and $\sin$ and $\cos$ are related?

Comment: Sorry la I am stupid!

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is either in quadrant $I$ or $II$, and $B$ is in quadrant $II$. So $A$ and then $B$ must be **both** in quadrant $II$, and this implies $\sin B > 0\Rightarrow \sin B = \sqrt{\sin^ 2B}= \sqrt{1-\cos^2B}= \sqrt{1-\dfrac{1}{\sec^2 B}} = \sqrt{1-\dfrac{1}{1+\tan^2B}}$. Can you plug the number into the formula and finish it?

Comment: TBH, WTF but thanks for answering!

Comment: One quibble.  Initially, we can only conclude that $B$ is in quadrant $II$ or $IV$.  The fact that $A$ and $B$ are in the same quadrant is what enables us to conclude that $A$ and $B$ must both be in quadrant $II$.